In Swin transformer Getting this Runtime error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x7 and 1024x5)
As stated in the title. I am getting the error shown there. The error occurs at the line where it says outputs = model(images). I am trying to use swin transformer for image classification on 5 classes and am fine tuning the last few layers only. Here is the code:
# Load the pre-trained Swin Transformer model
base_model = timm.create_model('swin_base_patch4_window7_224', pretrained=True)

# Modify the model to include global average pooling before the classification head
class SwinClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, base_model, num_classes):
        super(SwinClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.base_model = base_model
        self.global_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)  # Global average pooling to reduce spatial dimensions to 1x1
        self.fc = nn.Linear(base_model.num_features, num_classes)  # Fully connected layer
    

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.base_model.forward_features(x)  # Extract features
        print(f"Shape after forward_features: {x.shape}")  # Debugging line
        x = self.global_pool(x)  # Apply global average pooling (output shape: [batch_size, num_features, 1, 1])
        print(f"Shape after global pooling: {x.shape}")  # Debugging line
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten the tensor to shape [batch_size, num_features]
        print(f"Shape after flattening: {x.shape}")  # Debugging line
        x = self.fc(x)  # Classification head to get the final output
        return x

# Create an instance of the modified model
model = SwinClassifier(base_model, num_classes=5)

# Unfreeze the last 4 layers (blocks 9 to 12)
for name, param in model.base_model.named_parameters():
    if "layers.3.blocks.9" in name or "layers.3.blocks.10" in name or "layers.3.blocks.11" in name or "layers.3.blocks.12" in name:
        param.requires_grad = True  # Unfreeze the last 4 layers
    else:
        param.requires_grad = False  # Freeze the rest

# Ensure that the new head parameters are trainable
for param in model.fc.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

# Move model to device
model.to(device)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=0.001)

# Early stopping parameters
patience = 5  # Number of epochs with no improvement before stopping
best_val_loss = float('inf')  # Initialize the best validation loss to infinity
epochs_without_improvement = 0  # Counter to track epochs without improvement
best_model_wts = None  # To store the best model's weights

# Logging setup
logging.basicConfig(filename='train_log_MessiSwinFineTune3LyrAUCF1Kappa.txt', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

# a

epochs = 30  # Set the maximum number of epochs

for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    all_preds = []  # List to store all predictions for confusion matrix
    all_labels = []  # List to store all true labels for confusion matrix
    
    # Training loop
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        
       
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        # Zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Forward pass through the modified Swin model
        outputs = model(images)
        
        # Compute the loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Backward pass and optimization
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        # Statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        
        all_preds.extend(predicted.cpu().numpy())
        all_labels.extend(labels.cpu().numpy())
    
    train_acc = 100 * correct / total
    avg_train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    

Shape after forward_features: torch.Size([32, 7, 7, 1024])
Shape after global pooling: torch.Size([32, 7, 1, 1])
Shape after flattening: torch.Size([32, 7]) printed and runtime error saying  mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x7 and 1024x5)
Above is printed as the output along with the error. Can someone tell me what exactly is wrong.
